# How to really work in team on React Native project?

Tags: xcode, reactjs, react-native, ide, gitignore

**How do you work in team on react native projects?**

I'm working in Team of 2 people and having a lot of issues with working on the same project.

I don't understand how to properly create an environment so we can sync our code between each other while working on the same project. Now, we create a git repo with `/ios` and `/android` folders, but the thing is: the `/ios` folder always needs to be changed, because it links to the computer that was last building the project.

For example: we are working at the same time on different `.js` files and add a new `npm` dependency and we wish to sync our changes, so we commit changes to the Git repo and try to sync, this is where our pains begin.

The one need downloading the changed has to go to Xcode and manually update all the Framework Search Paths, Header Search Paths, delete libraries that Xcode doesn't see and then add them again.

I know it's moreof an Xcode problem, but I didn't see any detailed guide about team syncing in projects. I know that at Facebook people are doing a lot of cooperative work and I'd appreciate some input over our issues!

Comment: It is usually not a good idea to configure at the same time with multiple people. Better decide something in scrum and someone should take the lead. Otherwise solving these kind of conflicts kills too much time.

Comment: For me `prettier` setup is first. You guys should set up `prettier` for consistent style of code. https://prettier.io/docs/en/precommit.html

Comment: Also use Trello to divide tasks and assign to Each other, so you guys would be aware who is working on what part.

Comment: Some Xcode files do not need to be commited, and they are specific to your machines configurations. Make sure to add them in `.gitignore` file.

Comment: @Ziyo do you know exactly which files should be ignored by git?

Comment: I would say @Mukeyii 's answer is pretty good. But, be careful copying the whole thing. Maybe just copy Xcode and Android Studio part and add them to you gitignore file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using git, you can configure your .gitignore-file to prevent committing xcode-specific stuff and other configuration files.

I can highly recommend [**gitignore.io**](https://www.gitignore.io/), which is a *"web service designed to help you create .gitignore files for your Git repositories*"  [[Source]](https://github.com/joeblau/gitignore.io).

You can for example type in XCode (or AndroidStudio, ReactNative, Gradle, etc.) and it will automagically generate a .gitignore file for you.